# how to convert Flux<pojo> to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist, flux, spring-webclient

In my spring-boot springboot service class, I have created the following code which is not working as desired:

Service class:

```
Flux<Workspace> mWorkspace = webClient.get().uri(WORKSPACEID)
.retrieve().bodyToFlux(Workspace.class);

ArrayList<String> newmWorkspace = new ArrayList();
newmWorkspace = mWorkspace.blockLast();
return newmWorkspace;
```

Please someone help me on converting the list of json values to put it into arrayList

Json

```
[
{
"id:"123abc"
},
{
"id:"123abc"
}
]
```

Comment: are you having any error ?

Comment: yes like this, Type mismatch: cannot convert from Workspace to ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 1):

### Why is the code not working as desired

`mWorkspace`  is a publisher of one or many items of type Workspace.

Calling `newmWorkspace.blockLast()` will get a Workspace from that Publisher:
which is an object of type:  `Workspace` and not of type `ArrayList<String>`.

That's why :     `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Workspace to ArrayList<String>`

### Converting from Flux to an ArrayList

First of all, in reactive programming, a Flux is not meant to be blocked, the `blockxxx` methods are made for testing purposes. If you find yourself using them, then you may not need reactive logic.

In your service, you shall try this :

```
//initialize the list
ArrayList<String> newmWorkspace = new ArrayList<>();

Flux<Workspace> mWorkspace = webClient.get().uri(WORKSPACEID)
.retrieve().bodyToFlux(Workspace.class)
.map(workspace -> {
       //feed the list
       newmWorkspace.add(workspace.getId());
       return workspace;
});

 
//this line will trigger the publication of items, hence feeding the list
mWorkspace.subscribe();
```

### Just in case you want to convert a JSON String to a POJO:

```
String responseAsjsonString = "[{\"id\": \"123abc\"},{\"id\": \"123cba\"}] ";
Workspace[] workspaces = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseAsjsonString, Workspace[].class);
```

Comment: Actually i should return the values received from this method to another method as body
How can i do that i tried to return mWorkspace its giving error.

Comment: Then return mWorkspace (which is a Flux<Workspace>) instead of an arrayList - from the your method, the apply the map operation on the returned Flux in the other method. Meaning you arrayList will be fed in the other method.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually want to avoid blocking in a non-blocking application. However, if you are just integrating from blocking to non-blocking and doing so step-by-step (unless you are not mixing blocking and non-blocking in your production code), or using a servlet stack app but want to only use the WebFlux client, it should be fine.

With that being said, a Flux is a Publisher that represents an asynchronous sequence of `1..n` emitted items. When you do a `blockLast` you wait until the last signal completes, which resolves to a Workspace object.

You want to collect each resolved item to a list and return that. For this purpose, there is a useful method called `collectList`, which does this job without blocking the stream. You can then block the `Mono<List<Workspace>>` returned by this method to retrieve the list.

So this should give you the result you want:

```
List<Workspace> workspaceList = workspaceFlux.collectList().block();
```

If you must use a blocking call in the reactive stack, to avoid blocking the event loop, you should subscribe to it on a different scheduler. For the I/O purposes, you should use the `boundedElastic` Scheduler. You almost never want to call `block` on a reactive stack, instead subscribe to it. Or better let WebFlux to handle the subscription by returning the publisher from your controller (or Handler).